# how to query(parse.com) array match with an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, parse-platform

Please help me iam trying to write a query which match the array in the database(parse.com) with array from the user(array list)

```
final List<String> list = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.diagnosis_report));
// this is my array
    //Amniocentesis see Prenatal Testing            
    //>A1C                                       
    // Biopsy                                       
    // Blood Pressure see Vital Signs                 

searchSpinner.setItems(listArray, -1, new SpinnerListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemsSelected(List<KeyPairBoolData> items) {


               list1 = new ArrayList();

                    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                        if (items.get(i).isSelected()) {

                            list1.add(items.get(i).getName());

                            Log.i("TAG", i + " : " + items.get(i).getName() + " : " + items.get(i).isSelected());
                        }

                    }
                    Log.i("list", Arrays.toString(list1.toArray()));
                    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
```

> Blockquote this the query to match with array table but the query returns the elements which contains single or more elements in it

```
                            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("labTest");
                            query.whereNotContainedIn("testName",list1);
                            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                                    Log.i("count", String.valueOf(objects.size()));
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

> Blockquote
>   the array should contain all the elements which are in the list 
>   iam trying to match the subset of the list with the array
>   similar to the below code in a query.

```
  arrayContain(Arrays.asList(a), everyItem(isIn(b)));
```

Comment: Isn;t parse.com closed yet

Comment: Iam using back4app as service provider